# Creating new record for form on same page as listing all records causing weird results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have a form to add a new Department on the same page as the list of all departments with the ability to delete the Department on the same page. However, it seems by preparing an instance of Department for the form on departments#index creates an additional "blank" instance that is messing things up. Here's what I have:

### The form & list of departments:

```
= form_for @department do |f|
  - if @department.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@department.errors.count, 'error')
        prohibited this department from being saved:
      %ul
        - @department.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  .form-group
    %label Department Name
    = f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control', required: true
  .form-group
    = f.submit 'Add', :class => "btn btn-primary #{'disabled' if current_user.demo_mode}"

- if @departments.any?
  - @departments.each do |department|
    = department.name
    %br
    = link_to "Delete", department, method: :delete
```

### and the departments controller:

```
class DepartmentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @departments = current_user.company.departments
    @department = current_user.company.departments.new
  end

  def create
    current_user.company.departments.create(
      name: params[:department][:name]
    )
    redirect_to departments_path
  end

  def destroy
    department = current_user.company.departments.find(params[:id])
    department.destroy
    redirect_to departments_path, notice: 'Department was deleted.'
  end
```

But when there are no departments saved, it still lists one blank "delete" button that goes nowhere. @departments.any? is true no matter what here.

Is there a different way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is right here:

```
@departments = current_user.company.departments
@department = current_user.company.departments.new
```

The second line is adding a new empty Department in the list because it alters the reference of the departments' list. Plus you should use build instead of new.

To avoid the listing of the extra element, you can just use a collect or reject on the list and filter the empty (and hopefully not valid) element:

```
current_user.company.departments.select { |dep| dep.valid? }.each do ...
```

Or instead of putting the model in the relationship in the controller, do it when you're about to save. Like:

```
form_for Department.new do |f|
```

Then on the controller, save it on the right list (once you built the object from params).

```
current_user.company.departments << @department
```

Comment: right, I figured that was the problem...how about a solution? :)

Comment: Thanks...I didn't even know you can do form_for Department.net do |f|...very interesting. thanks I will try this when I get home!

Answer (score -1):

I guess the empty record is creating when you are submitting the form without the name field is entered.

Modify your create method as follows: 
  def create
    current_user.company.departments.create(
      name: params[:department][:name] 
    ) 
 **if params[:department][:name].present?** 
    redirect_to departments_path 
  end

Creating empty records can be avoided with conditional statement. is'nt it?

Also, I could see some unwanted queries in delete action:

```
department = current_user.company.departments.find(params[:id])
department.destroy
```

can be modified to

```
department = Department.find_by_id(params[:id])
department.destroy
```

You are finding department object based on the param id, so it is not necessary for nesting associated models.

This may help you..

Thanks !!